# General Query for Database

Tags: sql

I have two tables i.e. A and B. In each table one attribute of each tuple is time stamp. The latest time stamp can appear in table B.

My question is : I want to select tuples from both tables but if a tuple of A having same ID in B then latest time stamp tuple should be appeared from table B.

Can anyone help me how to write this query? I am looking to answer of this problem specific as well as in general.

Comment: If you also desire an specific solution, what’s the query you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

There's not one way in general to solve it - a common way is something like:

```
   SELECT * FROM A
   INNER JOIN B 
     ON A.ID = B.ID
         AND B.TIMESTAMP = (SELECT MAX(TIMESTAMP) FROM B b2 WHERE b2.ID = A.ID)
```